# How to convert the results into a specified form?

Tags: equation-solving

```
2/5 (-1)^(2 n) - 1/15 (-1)^n 2^(4 - 2 n)
```

How can the above equation be transformed into:

```
2/5 + 4/15 (-1/4)^(n - 1)
```

Where n is a natural number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Simplify[2/5 (-1)^(2 n) - 1/15 (-1)^n 2^(4 - 2 n),Element[n, PositiveIntegers]]
(*1/15 (6 + (-1)^(1 + n) 4^(2 - n))*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you assume n is even integer

```
s1 = 2/5  (-1)^(2  n) - 1/15  (-1)^n  2^(4 - 2  n)
s2 = Simplify[s1, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && Mod[n, 2] == 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
s2 = 2/5 + 4/15  (-1/4)^(n - 1)
FullSimplify[s1-s2,Assumptions->Element[n,Integers]&&Mod[n,2]==1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]